# maven project which has both java and scala

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven

I want to build a maven project which has both java and scala source code.
I have installed scala IDE plugin in eclipse and added the **"scala-maven-plugin"**  in pom.xml but the imports of java classes in the scala files are giving compilation errors.
Which is the best IDE to build such mixed projects?

The project structure is

[image]

The pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-examples_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
<!-- This plugin compiles Scala files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
<!-- This plugin compiles Java files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
<!-- This plugin adds all dependencies to JAR file during 'package' command.
Pay EXTRA attention to the 'mainClass' tag. 
You have to set name of class with entry point to program ('main' method) -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ScalaRunner</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>  
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: First you should move you Scala into a different package than the `default`...

Answer (score 5):

It seems from your code structure that your Scala classes depend on Java, not the other way around. Yet in your Maven config, Scala gets compiled first. Change it to compile after Java classes.

The following plugin sequence works in my project:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its safest to go straight to the [page provided by the scala-maven-plugin docs](https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html) where you can find the current pom definition which supports dependencies in both directions